# Problem displaying fermat numbers greater than n = 5

Tags: c

I am starting my work to finish my university degree and I encounter a problem in C++ to show fermat numbers greater than n = 5

I don't understand why, for n = 5, the last number writes a 6 when it must be a 7.

I pass you a very simple code since I first have to solve this problem before starting with the final program.

```
int n=0;
long double resultado;


 printf ("\n\n MOSTRAR LOS DIEZ PRIMEROS NUMEROS DE FERMAT:\n");
 printf ( "-------------------------------------\n");
 printf(" Los numeros son los siguientes ");


while(n<10)
{

        resultado= pow(2, pow(2, n)) + 1;
        n++;
        printf("%.Lf \n", resultado);


}
```

Comment: double upper = 1;
      double fer = 2;
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         System.out.println(fer + 1);
         upper *= 2;
         fer = (long) Math.pow(2, upper);
      }

Comment: `pow` is a floating point function, use multiplication by 2 (or left shift) instead

Comment: You can't rely on floating point types to produce [exact results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QQ3nCMlM1e5K8VzS), because they have limited precision. If you need that kind of accuracy, you should use an arbitrary-precision numeric type provided by some external library.

Answer (score 0):

```
  double upper = 1;
  double fer = 2;
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
     System.out.println(fer + 1);
     upper *= 2;
     fer = (long) Math.pow(2, upper);
  }
```

Note that after the 7th term the Fermat number is greater than 10^18 and thus cannot be exactly represented in a double (Only about 16-17 place accuracy in 64 bit double value).

Comment: Thanks but I'm going to show an image to show that I really can write those numbers but I change the last 6 for a 7 and I don't understand why.

Comment: 18446744073709551616 (<-- must be 7 not six)
340282366920938463463374607431768211456(<-- must be 7 not six)
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936(<-- must be 7 not six)

Comment: There's no `System.out.println` in C++